# RegEx for catching structs and unions

Tags: regex

I am trying to catch unions and structures with regular expressions. The full match will catch the whole structure and group1 will catch the members.

```
struct Name
{
  uint16 member1;
  uint16 member2;
};

union Name
{
  uint16 member1;
  uint16 member2;
};
```

When trying to find a specific union it works as expected with:

```
r"union Name[\s\S]*{\s*([\s\S]*)};"
```

but when trying to find a specific struct I use the regular expression:

```
r"struct Name[\s\S]*{\s*([\s\S]*)};"
```

which is identical except that union is replaced by struct. The regular expression for catching the struct just continues matching all the lines following the structure and I do not understand why, because it does not for the union case and I do not understand why?

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to match here?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/P62RYE/2

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/sfbyJI/1